# Отметьте те числа, которые могут быть результатом работы автомата

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Автомат получает на вход два трехзначных числа без ведущих нулей. По этим числам
строится новое число по следующим правилам.

1. Вычисляются три числа – сумма старших разрядов заданных трехзначных чисел, сумма
   средних разрядов этих чисел, сумма младших разрядов.
2. Полученные три числа (без ведущих нулей) записываются друг за другом в порядке
   невозрастания. Отметьте те числа, которые могут быть результатом работы автомата.

1) 151303

2) 161410

3) 191615

4) 16123

5) 210

6) 111

7) 12101

Моя попытка решить:

разбивка 5 и 10 и 14, потому что максимум 9+9=18

Подберем цифру старшего разряда, она должна быть самая большая

5-3 = 2

10-3 = 7

14-3 = 11 > 9 не подходит

Максимум 7 и формирует она число 10

Следующий разряд

5-6 = -1 не подходит

14-6 = 8

Максимум 8 и формирует число 14

Последнее

5-5 = 0

Результат 780

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проще подобрать :) Вариантов много, но вот по одному:

```
161410 : 158  998
 16123 : 159  277
   210 : 100  101
 12101 : 103  919
```

А вот 151303,  191615  и 111 - не получится.

111 - очевидно: это только три единицы, а два трехзначных меньше 2 дать не могут. 0 в начале тоже невозможен.

191615 - очевидны 19, 16 и 15. Но 19 - не получится никак...

151303 - 0 может принадлежать только 30. А 30 - заведомо много...

Comment: и итоговый ответ....??

Comment: Ну не прикалывайтесь :)

Comment: :)ладно спасибо за решение)))

Comment: "111 - не получится"----Имеется ввиду, что минимальное число — 100?

Comment: Имеется в виду, что это - три суммы по 1. Что может быть только как 1+0. Значит, если первая цифра одного числа - 1, то второго - 0, а значит, оно уже не трехзначное.